# sql query for selecting field with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
BILL_NO COUTER TRANTYPE BARCODE DES                  TRANAMT 
164     1      V        21021   ALOKOZAY TISSUE 150S (3.50) 
164     1      s        21021   210521 CABAGE         5.00 
164     1      C        CASH    CASH                  1.50 
208     2      V        120110  NATCO ORANGE MARMALA (6.75) 
208     2      S        120110  NATCO ORANGE MARMALA  6.75 
208     2      C        CASH    CASH                   -
164     3      S        5404568 FRESH FISH           18.00 
164     3      S        5406464 ARYAA IDLY/DOSA MIX   5.00 
164     3      S        654954  DETTOL SENSITIVE 125  7.00 
164     3      C        CASH    CASH                 30.00
```

i want select bill no  from my table where trantype='v'

but i need result as metioned below thank you

```
BILL_NO COUTER TRANTYPE BARCODE DES                  TRANAMT 
164     1      V        21021   ALOKOZAY TISSUE 150S (3.50) 
164     1      s        21021   210521 CABAGE         5.00 
164     1      C        CASH    CASH                  1.50 
208     2      V        120110  NATCO ORANGE MARMALA (6.75) 
208     2      S        120110  NATCO ORANGE MARMALA  6.75
```

Comment: please describe the logic to get to the requested result. It is not obvious. For instance: why is TRANTYPE C for Bill_NO 208 missing?

Comment: So what`s the logic?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me, but I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where exists (select 42
              from the_table t2
              where t2.bill_no = t1.bill_no
                and t2.trantype = 'V'
                and t2.couter = t1.couter);
```

That would return `bill_no = 208` and `trantype = 'C'` as well (which is not part of your example output). But as you didn't explain that missing row it's hard to write a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the missing row for Bill_no 208 is just a typo, the following solution might help:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT BILL_NO, COUNTER
 FROM YourTable WHERE TRANTYPE ='V'
)
SELECT yt.*
FROM YourTable yt
INNER JOIN cte ON yt.BILL_NO = cte.BILL_NO AND yt.COUNTER=cte.COUNTER
```